# Unittest mock patch not creating a mock for method

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Here is the proj structure that I have -

```
src/
    package1/
       __init__.py
       file1.py # has the method -> _method_name
       
    tests/
       __init__.py
       test_file1.py
```

I am using unittest to test my code. I want to mock a method in a package1 and run my tests. Here is what i am doing to mock that method -

```
with unittest.mock.patch('package1.file1._method_name') as method_name_mock:
```

This should create a MagicMock for the method name. When i start debugging, it invokes the real method which i don't want.

I am checking if the mock was called twice which it should but somehow it fails since the real method gets called -

```
assert method_name_mock.call_count == 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably patching the wrong object - this depends on how you import the method in the real code. Please check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: ah correct. Was using patch wrong. Thanks